# stringstream: dec int to hex to car conversion issue

Tags: c++, char, hex, stringstream

I was trying some simple exercises with stringstream, when I came across this problem. Following program takes an int number, saves it in stringstream in hex format and then displays whether a int in decimal and char are available in string.
I ran it for different inputs and it is not working properly for some of them.
Please see the detail below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int roll;
  stringstream str_stream;
  cout << "enter an integer\n";
  cin>>roll;
  str_stream << hex << roll;

  if(str_stream>>dec>>roll){ 
    cout << "value of int is " << roll << "\n";
  }
  else
    cout << "int not fount \n";
  char y;

  if(str_stream>>y){
    cout << "value of char is "<<  y << endl; 
  }
  else
    cout << "char not found \n";
  cout << str_stream.str() << "\n";
}
```

I ran it for 3 different inputs:
 `Case1:
    {
enter an integer
9
value of int is 9
char not found 
9`

Case2:
`enter an integer
31
value of int is 1
value of char is f
1f`

Case3:
`enter an integer
12
int not fount 
char not found 
c`

In case 1 &2. program is working as expected but in case 3, it should found a char, I am not sure why it is not able to find char in stream.

Regards,
Navnish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `if(str_stream>>dec>>roll)` fails to read anything then the state of the stream is set to `fail(false)`. After that any further read operation using that stream will not be successful(and returns false) unless you reset the state of the stream using `clear()`.

So:

```
 .....//other code
 if(str_stream>>dec>>roll){ 
    cout << "value of int is " << roll << "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "int not fount \n";
    str_stream.clear();//*******clears the state of the stream,after reading failed*********
  }
  char y;

  if(str_stream>>y){
    cout << "value of char is "<<  y << endl; 
  }
  else
    cout << "char not found \n";

....//other code
```

Comment: Thanks, after using fail() and clear() functions, program is working fine.